# unpacking an unknown serialised format with variable length

Tags: perl, binary, unpack

I'm using Perl (5.8.8, don't ask) and I'm looking at a serialised binary file that I want to parse and snaffle information from.

The format is as follows:

- 7 bytes whose meaning I do not know (DB DB 00 00 7A 03 00)
- null (0x00)
- 7-byte string with user id
- null (0x00)
- 12-byte string to be discarded
- null (0x00)
- 3-byte number specifying number of items to follow
- null (0x00)
- variable-length string for first item
- newline (0x0a)
- variable-length string for second item
- newline (0x0a)
- etc ...
- null (0x00)
- 7-byte string with user id
- etc ...

My current code somewhat naively skips the first 8 bytes, then reads byte per byte until it hits a null and then does very specific parsing.

```
sub readGroupsFile {
    my %index;

    open (my $fh, "<:raw", "groupsfile");
    seek($fh, 8, 0);
    while (read($fh, my $userID, 7)) {
        $index{$userID} = ();
        seek($fh, 18, 1);
        my $groups = "";
        while (read($fh, my $byte, 1)) {
            last if (ord($byte) == 0);
            $groups .= $byte;
        }
        my @grouplist = split("\n", $groups);
        $index{$userID} = \@grouplist;
    }
    close($fh);

    return \%index;
}
```

Good news? It works.

However, I think it's not very elegant, and wonder if I can use the 2-byte number that specifies the amount of items to follow to my advantage to speed up the parsing. I have no idea why else it would be there.

I think `unpack()` and its templates may provide an answer, but I can't figure out how it can work with variable-length arrays of strings with their own variable lengths.

Comment: Why are you seeking 18? it seems like it should be 20 according to the data you give: 0x0 + 15 byte str + 0x0 + 2 byte + 0x0 = 20

Comment: I think the problem is that `unpack` needs a string to unpack from, it cannot read directly from the file. So you need to read the file into a string first, but that might not be very efficient compared to what you have

Comment: apologies, it's actually a 12-byte string and the number may be 3 bytes. +3 nulls is 18. I miscounted. But the real issue is in the array following it. I've adjusted the post.

Comment: Once you get to "_variable-length string_" items can switch to `readline` (aka `<>`) since they all end with newline.  There is no reason to not be able to mix `read` and `<>`, I think (just not `sysread`, which is unbuffered).

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is with "_variable length arrays_" ... that you don't know how many "_variable length strings_" there are? Once you switch to `readline` ou can test every line you read for a 7-byte string ending with null; by description it seems that no "item" can be like that.

Comment: Or: set `local $/` to the nul, then read four such "lines" (discard -- user ID -- discard -- number of items to follow); Then change `$/` back to newline, and using the last one just read (number of items) read that many lines (items).  Repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no idea how much to read, so reading in the whole file at once will get you the best speed results.

```
{
   my $file = do { local $/; <> };

   $file =~ s/^.{8}//s
      or die("Bad data");

   while (length($file)) {
      $file =~ s/^([^\0]*)\0[^\0]*\0[^\0]*\0([^\0]*)\0//
         or die("Bad data");

      my $user_id = $1;
      my @items = split(/\n/, $2, -1);
      ...
   }
}
```

By using a buffer, you can get most of the benefits of reading in the whole file at once without actually reading the whole file in at once, but it will make the code more complicated.

```
{
   my $buf = '';
   my $not_eof = 1;

   my $reader = sub {
      $not_eof &&= read(\*ARGV, $buf, 1024*1024, length($buf));
      die($!) if !defined($not_eof);
      return $not_eof;
   };

   while ($buf !~ s/^.{8}//s) {
      $reader->()
         or die("Bad data");
   }      

   while (length($buf) || $reader->()) {
      my $user_id;
      my @items;
      while (1) {
         if ($buf =~ s/^([^\0]*)\0[^\0]*\0[^\0]*\0([^\0]*)\0//) {
            $user_id = $1;
            @items = split(/\n/, $2, -1);
            last;
         }

         $reader->()
            or die("Bad data");
      }

      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. So the second approach will not consume as much memory as the first approach if the file is large, but the speed will be approximately the same I guess?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, If the size of the records are usually less than the buffer size, then it should be comparable in speed (because the loops effectively collapse into "if" statements). You can make it use less memory by extracting a field at a time rather than a record at a time, but that's probably not needed. /// Note that a bad file (such as a large file without any NULs) could end up being loaded entirely into memory, but that's easy to avoid by throwing an error in `&$reader` if the buffer gets too large.

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable. But something else: In the second snippet I should `$file` be replaced by `$buf` ?

Comment: Thanks! I am still not able to see how it will work at the boundary between the blocks. Let's say a record does not end exactly at the buffer boundary. Then the inner `while` will fail, and next `reader->()` is called, which overwrites the whole buffer. Won't that record then be lost?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, `&$reader` doesn't overwrite; it appends. (Note the fourth arg of `read`.)

Comment: Of course, I totally missed that `length($buf)` is the offset in the call to `read`.

Comment: interesting use of Perl. I am clearly showing my PHP beginnings :)

Comment: I would use the same approach in PHP.

Comment: This was the fastest method (on average about 0.01s faster) with a 1024 byte buffer. Oddly, I had to change the regex to `s/^([^\0]*)\0([^\0]*)\0([^\0]*)\0([^\0]*)\0([^\0]*)\0([^\0]*)\0//)` (uid, dn, n_groups, expires, groups -- capture groups not necessary). Even after correcting for the bit of data I had overlooked (expires), this is still one more field than there actually is in the binary format. Maybe the asterisk doesn't quite behave as expected with binary? With a plus (+) I wasn't getting matches.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to reduce the number of hard-coded specifics, based on data description; one reads by those null bytes (then changes back to newlines), the other `unpack`s lines with nuls.

Set [`$/` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) to the null byte, and read first 4 (four) such "lines."  You get your user ID there, and then the last such "line" read is the number of items that follows. Restore `$/` to newline and read that list, using normal [`readline`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) (aka [`<>`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators)).  Repeat, if this pattern indeed repeats.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 file\n";  # a_file_with_nuls.txt    
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!"; 

my ($user_id, $num_items);
while (not eof $fh) {    
    READ_BY_NUL: { 
        my $num_of_nul_lines = 4;
        local $/ = "\x00"; 
        my $line;
        for my $i (1..$num_of_nul_lines) { 
            $line = readline $fh;
            chop $line;
            if ($i == 2) {
                $user_id = $line;
            }
        }   
        $num_items = $line;  # last nul-terminated "line"
    }        
    say "Got: user-id = |$user_id|, and number-of-items = |$num_items|";    

    my @items;
    for (1..$num_items) {
        my $line = readline $fh;
        chomp $line;
        push @items, $line;
    }    
    say for @items;
};
```

Since `$/` is set using [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) in `READ_BY_NUL` block, its previous value is restored out of the block.

The output is as expected, but please add checks. Also, one can imagine errors on which it would make sense to recover (for example: actual number of items falls short of the given number).

The whole thing is in a `while` with a manual check (and termination) using [eof](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html), per assumption that the pattern *four-nuls + number-of-lines* indeed repeats (a little unclear from the question).

I test with a file made by

```
perl -wE'say "toss\x00user-id\x00this-too\x003\x00item-1\nitem2\nitem 3"' 
    > a_file_with_nuls.txt
```

which is then appended multiple times to give us something for that `while` loop.

Finally, make that read `<:raw` on systems which need it and `unpack` as needed. See below.

---

As stated in the question, (some?) data is binary so what is read above need be `upack`-ed. That also means that there may be problems with reading up to null bytes -- how was that data written in the first place? It is possible for unfilled parts of those fixed-width fields to be filled exactly *with nuls*.

Another option altogether is to simply read lines, and [unpack](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) the first one (and then `unpack` one line every time after the given number of lines, specified as "items," has been read).

```
open my $fh, '<:raw', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!"; 

my @items;
my $block_lines = 1;

while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
    chomp $line;
    if ( $. % $block_lines == 0 ) {
        my ($uid, $num_items) = unpack "x8 A7x x13 i3x", $line;
        say "User-id: $uid, read $num_items lines for items";
        $block_lines += 1 + $num_items;
    }   
    else {
        push @items, $line;
    }
}
say for @items;
```

Here the number of bytes to skip (`x8` and `x13`) includes the zero.

This assumes that the number of "items" (lines) to read in every "block" may be different, and adds them up as it goes (plus the line with nuls, for total running `$block_lines`) so to able to check when it is again at a line with nuls (`$. % $block_lines == 0`)

It makes a few other (reasonable) assumptions for things which aren't specified. This has been checked only lightly, with some made up data.

Comment: will be able to test when I return to the office on Monday, but one remark is that the number of items number is actually in binary. Is is enough to simply readline it and then unpack?

Comment: @bluppfisk Ah, right -- it should be fine. (And you want to open in `<raw`, as you do.)

Comment: @bluppfisk If the layout of your real data differs significantly post some, so that I can test

Comment: @bluppfisk Updated, but this may need tweaks -- let me know how it goes

Comment: got this to work too with minor changes (needed to read another NULL before continuing the while loop) but ikegami's solution is marginally faster. Thanks for showing me these options, though, always happy to learn more.